# What is the most convenient way to bind events to template literals in web components?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, web-component

I've been working on web components lately and one thing that I miss from angular/react is the automatic binding of methods to `this` scope of the class. I suppose it's called declarative. Is there anything that emulates this behavior in vanilla JS?

```
export class QuickMenuCmp extends HTMLElement {

    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        this.innerHTML = this.template;

        // The "type a lot way"
        document.querySelector('quick-menu-vsc > .navigator')
            .addEventListener('click', () => this.toggleNavMenu())

        // The "polute the global scope" way
        (<any>window).toggleNavMenu = this.toggleNavMenu;

        // Or the "alias" method using bling.js
        $('quick-menu-vsc > .navigator').on('click', el => this.toggleNavMenu());

        // All of them imperative
    }

    get template() {
        return `
            <div class="button ${this.isNavMenuVis ? 'active' : ''}" 
                onclick="toggleNavMenu()" title="Lessons menu">
                <i class="fa fa-list" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
        `;
    }

    private toggleNavMenu(){
        console.warn('toggleNavMenu');
    }

}

// Component
require('./quick-menu.cmp.scss');
window.customElements.define('quick-menu-vsc', QuickMenuCmp);
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't played with web components yet, but I think the issue is simply how this is bound in javascript. You'll need to bind this within the function or use the parent's scope by assigning it with an arrow function.

Try this:

```
export class QuickMenuCmp extends HTMLElement {

    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    connectedCallback = () => {
        this.innerHTML = this.template;

        // The "type a lot way"
        document.querySelector('quick-menu-vsc > .navigator')
            .addEventListener('click', () => this.toggleNavMenu())

        // The "polute the global scope" way
        (<any>window).toggleNavMenu = this.toggleNavMenu;

        // Or the "alias" method using bling.js
        $('quick-menu-vsc > .navigator').on('click', el => this.toggleNavMenu());

        // All of them imperative
    }

    get template() {
        return `
            <div class="button ${this.isNavMenuVis ? 'active' : ''}" 
                onclick="toggleNavMenu()" title="Lessons menu">
                <i class="fa fa-list" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
        `;
    }

    private toggleNavMenu = () => {
        console.warn('toggleNavMenu');
    }

}

// Component
require('./quick-menu.cmp.scss');
window.customElements.define('quick-menu-vsc', QuickMenuCmp);
```